# Spacing after first line of math mode

Tags: math-mode

Using this input

```
\section*{Opgave 3}
En differentialligning har forskriften
\[\dyx=0.02\frac{450-y}{450}y\]
På løsningskurven ligger punkterne
\[A=(0,30)\]
\[B=(10,36.11)\]
\[C=(20,43.33)\]
\subsection*{Bestem linjeelementerne $(x,y,\alpha)$ i $A, B$ og $C$}
Siden $x$- og $y$-værdierne er kendte, skal $\alpha$ blot udregnes for hvert punkt, ved at indsætte punktets koordinater i differentialliningen:
\[\alpha_A=0.02\cdot\frac{450-30}{450}\cdot30=0.56\]
\[\alpha_B=0.02\cdot\frac{450-36.11}{450}\cdot36.11=0.6642\]
\[\alpha_C=0.02\cdot\frac{450-43.33}{450}\cdot43.33=0.7832\]
Hvilket medfører at de tre linjeelementer er:
\[A=(0,30,0.56)\]
\[B=(10,36.11,0.6642)\]
\[C=(20,43.33,0.7832)\]
```

Leaves a much larger spacing between the first two lines of math than between the second and third in every triplet:

[image]

Any way to fix this?

Comment: You should never use two consecutive math environments: use `gather` or `align`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uneven spacing is due to the consecutive `displaymath` environments; this is something to carefully avoid. The `amsmath` package provides the necessary tools, namely `align*` and `gather*`; in the example below I show two different realizations for the *A*, *B* and *C* cases, take your pick. In the middle display, I add some vertical spaces because of the fractions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\der}[2]{\frac{d#1}{d#2}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Opgave 3}
En differentialligning har forskriften
\[
\der{y}{x}=0.02\frac{450-y}{450}y
\]
På løsningskurven ligger punkterne
\begin{gather*}
A=(0,30) \\
B=(10,36.11) \\
C=(20,43.33)
\end{gather*}
\subsection*{Bestem linjeelementerne $(x,y,\alpha)$ i $A, B$ og $C$}
Siden $x$- og $y$-værdierne er kendte, skal $\alpha$ blot udregnes 
for hvert punkt, ved at indsætte punktets koordinater i differentialliningen:
\begin{align*}
\alpha_A&=0.02\cdot\frac{450-30}{450}\cdot30=0.56 \\[1ex]
\alpha_B&=0.02\cdot\frac{450-36.11}{450}\cdot36.11=0.6642 \\[1ex]
\alpha_C&=0.02\cdot\frac{450-43.33}{450}\cdot43.33=0.7832
\end{align*}
Hvilket medfører at de tre linjeelementer er:
\begin{align*}
A&=(0,30,0.56) \\
B&=(10,36.11,0.6642) \\
C&=(20,43.33,0.7832)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]